Could there be spiritual repercussions for someone who depends financially on a sinner?
If a person depends financially almost entirely on donations from another person, and that person is a sinner, would the receiver of the money face spiritual repercussions?

ולא עוד אלא שאפלו אם עשה מצוה בזמן מלאכתו, לא לצדקה תחשב לו, אלא עברה היא בידו, שאין עברה מצוה, וקרא כתיב (ישעיה סא): שונא גזל בעולה, וכענין זה אמרו זכרונם לברכה (בבא קמא צד): הרי שגזל סאה חטים וטחנה ואפאה ומברך, אין זה מברך אלא מנאץ, דכתיב (תהלים י): ובצע ברך נאץ ה׳

Since there are multiple questions here, and not all of them are Torah-related, I’ll address one that is not specific to Torah:
If you define “financial stability” as “financial independence,” i.e. no longer having to rely on tzedakah, then she would have more trouble reaching financial stability if she is relying on anyone’s tzedakah, not just that of a sinner.
You should CYLOR, but:
Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 34:15-16:

לְעוֹלָם יַרְחִיק אָדָם אֶת עַצְמוֹ מִן הַצְּדָקָה, וִיגַלְגֵל עַצְמוֹ
בְצַעַר, שֶׁלֹּא יִצְטָרֵךְ לַבְּרִיּוֹת. וְכֵן צִוּוּ חֲכָמֵינוּ
זִכְרוֹנָם לִבְרָכָה, עֲשֵׂה שַׁבַּתְּךָ חֹל וְאַל תִּצְטָרֵךְ
לַבְּרִיּוֹת. וַאֲפִלּוּ הָיָה חָכָם מְכֻבָּד וְהֶעֱנִי, יַעֲסֹק
בְּאֻמָּנוּת וַאֲפִלּוּ בְּאֻמָּנוּת מְנֻוֶּלֶת, וְאַל יִצְטָרֵךְ
לַבְּרִיּוֹת.
A person should always avoid taking charity. He should suffer hardship
rather than depend on people. And so did our Sages of blessed memory
command, "Make your Sabbath like a weekday rather than be dependent
upon others." Even if an honored scholar becomes impoverished, he
should find some occupation even a lowly job, rather than depend on
people.
כָּל מִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לִטּוֹל מֵהַצְּדָקָה, וּמְרַמֶּה אֵת
הַבְּרִיּוֹת וְנוֹטֵל, אֵינוֹ מֵת עַד שֶׁיִּצְטָרֵךְ לַבְּרִיּוֹת.
וְכָל מִי שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לִטּוֹל, וְאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לִחְיוֹת אֶלָּא אִם
כֵּן יִטּוֹל, כְּגוֹן זָקֵן אוֹ חוֹלֶה אוֹ בַּעַל יִסּוּרִין, וּמֵגִיס
דַּעְתּוֹ וְאֵינוֹ נוֹטֵל, הֲרֵי זֶה שׁוֹפֵךְ דָּמִים וּמִתְחַיֵּב
בְּנַפְשׁוֹ, וְאֵין לוֹ בְּצַעֲרוֹ אֶלָּא עֲווֹנוֹת וַחֲטָאִים. וְכָל
מִי שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לִטּוֹל וּמְצַעֵר עַצְמוֹ, וְדוֹחֵק אֶת הַשָּׁעָה
וְחַי חַיֵּי צַעַר, כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יַטְרִיחַ עַל הַצִּבּוּר, אֵינוֹ
מֵת עַד שֶׁיְפַרְנֵס אֲחֵרִים, וְעָלָיו הַכָּתוּב אוֹמֵר, בָּרוּךְ
הַגֶּבֶר אֲשֶׁר יִבְטַח בַּה' וְגוֹ' (רנ"ה).
Whoever has no need to take charity, and deceives people and takes,
will not die before actually needing charity. Anyone who needs to take
[charity], and cannot survive unless he takes [charity], for example,
one who is old, sick or suffering, but whose pride doesn't allow him
to take [charity], sheds [his own] blood and is liable for his own
life, and all he has for his suffering are sins. Anyone who needs
[charity] and inflicts himself with suffering and "bides his time,"
and lives a life of suffering in order not to burden the community,
will not die before acquiring the means to support others. And about
him it is said: "Blessed is the man who trusts in Hashem.

